# C/C++ library for platform-independent binary file I/O

Tags: c++, file, binary, io

I've been trying for months to find a small C or C++ library for platform-independent binary file I/O, that means endian swapping and with fixed size types.

I know that huge libraries like wxWidgets and Qt have them, and that languages like Java and C# also have them, but I'd prefer to use a small library instead of a huge framework.

Comment: Oh, over 7 years have passed... Did you find it?

Comment: Probably libuv would be a good option: http://libuv.org/

Answer (score 3):

How about Google [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)?

The library includes bindings for C++, Java and Python.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

One of it's goals is "Data Portability - Streams of bytes created on one platform should be readable on any other."

There are also links to other libraries providing similar functionality.

Comment: Wow! what a perfect example of a *tiny* library for I/O :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use fstream that comes packaged in with all C++ compilers. You just set the ios::binary flag and make plentiful use of sizeof to make it OS independent. E.g.: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall02/binio.html and   http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorial-on-file-operations/c-file-i-o-binary-files-using-fstream.aspx

Comment: In my experience, using fstream gets very messy (long and repetitive lines, lots of casts), even without handling platform-dependent stuff.

Comment: No need to translate binary input IMO. Just go std library here.

Comment: Because it's a massive pain in the ass, and doesn't even work with binary without resorting to disgusting hacks like casting the int to a char...

Answer (score 1):

For most file format work I prefer to use sqlite : http://www.sqlite.org/ the cool thing is you can access the same data file across operating systems *and* programming languages *and* devices.

Comment: SQLite is not useful for storing the type of data like voxel volumes